# Loop error upon entering duplicate data

Tags: excel, web, vba

The code I created encounters error and the process of iterating the survey creation stops whenever there's a duplicate data.

The error points to `IE.Document.all("onetidListTitle").Value = ttle & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & count)` since the webpage redirected to error page after duplicate is detected.

The website does not pops-out error message, instead it is being redirected to a new webpage.

Now my question is, what code I need to add for the process to skip the duplicated data and proceed on the iteration of survey creation?

Below is the code i created;

```
Sub Survey()
Dim IE As Object
Dim Status, Stat, ttle, link As String
Dim count, repeat As Integer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Stat = "Complete"
ttle = "User Survey "
count = 6
Status = Range("C" & count).Value

Do Until Status <> ""
    If Status = "" Then
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & count) <> "" Then
            IE.Navigate "http://..."
            link = "http://..." & ttle & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & count) & "/overview.aspx"
            IE.Visible = False

            While IE.Busy
                DoEvents
            Wend

            delay 1
            IE.Document.all("onetidListTitle").Value = ttle & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & count)
            delay 1
            IE.Document.all("onetidDisplayOnLeftNo").Click
            delay 1
            IE.Document.all("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_onetidCreateSurvey").Click
            Range("C" & count).Value = Stat

            Range("D" & count).Value = link
        End If
        delay 1
    count = count + 1
    End If
    delay 1
Loop
End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?  What are you trying to do -- Open and log into a list of websites?  Which part is "duplicated"?

Comment: What i am trying to do is open a website then fill out a form. The duplicate part is the title, it should be updated on this id `onetidListTitle`.